# How to create inline stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Looking to recreate these stroke styles in illustrator but being such a newbie to this, I definitely don't even have the terminology correct for this one.

Currently using the pen tool but my strokes are solid and I am not sure how to add 1. the inline stroke and 2. "bubble" or give that "inflated round radius" at the end of the lines. For smaller screen resolutions I don't need the inline stroke but would still like to have the same end cap styles.

Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

[image: inline stroke and end caps]

[image: end caps]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create the "bubble" on the end...

First draw a path and set the end cap to be rounded:

[image]

Then use the **Width Tool** to make one end of the stroke wider, then still using the Width Tool, set a counter-width below the end point to constrict the path before the end. You should see the "bubble" form..

[image]

To add an "inline" stroke, use the **Appearance Panel** to add an additional stroke....

Click-drag the existing stroke to the `New` icon at the bottom of the Appearance panel to duplicate it (this makes certain the width points duplicate as well). Then change the color and weight of the new stroke...

[image]

> **CS6 NOTE:** You can merely add a new stroke in the Appearance Panel for CS6, the width adjustments will apply to new Appearance Panel strokes in CS6. In CC2017, the width adjustments DO NOT apply to new Appearance panel strokes *[possible bug]* - so you MUST duplicate the existing stroke and alter the duplicate rather than merely adding a new stroke in CC2017.

If you want to refine further, you can choose `Object > Expand Appearance` an you'll have 2 *shapes* which you can then alter independently of one another.

[image]